# Firebase functions > 1min

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to setup a small webshop and firebase functions is the tool that I use to safely **create** and **update** the payment node in firebase.

The user is redirected to a 3rd party payment service when the payment is created.

With these **two** functions I am experiencing a so called "cold start".

When a function is cold and needs to be warmed up, it takes > 1min for the user to be redirected and to have both functions well executed. When the function is warmed up, everything is working fine and times are less then 5s, which I find acceptable when the user gets redirected to another website.

I would like to have them warm all the time, so these are the options that I consider:

1. Using cron-jobs(https://cron-job.org/en) to trigger every 6 min a function so that they don't run cold.
2. Write better code.
3. All other ideas are more than welcome!

The first option isn't waterproof, some times it runs cold and sometimes not. And writing better code, well that's where I need help. Here is the most important function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as request from 'request-promise-native';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const mollieCreatePayment = functions.database
    .ref('/orders/{orderId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const order = event.data.val();
        const orderId = event.params.orderId;
        const userId = order.userId;

        const optionsAPI = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://api.mollie.nl/v1/payments',
            body: {
                "amount": totalAmount,
                "description": "Bestelling " + orderId,
                "redirectUrl": environmentVariables.domainUrl + "/order-success/" + orderId,
                "webhookUrl": environmentVariables.webhookUrl
            },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + environmentVariables.mollieKey
            },
            json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
        };
        request(optionsAPI)
            .then(async mollieResponse => {
                await updateOrCreatePaymentInDb(userId, orderId, mollieResponse);
                await updatePaymentIdInOrder(orderId, mollieResponse.id);
                return;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a promise from this function that completes when all the asynchronous work is complete.  Failure to return a promise from background functions (non-HTTP functions) may cause the function to time out, because Cloud Functions doesn't know when the work is fully complete.

Using a mixture of promises and async/await seems like kind of an anti-pattern to me.  IMO you should either chain promises or use a series of awaits, not both, and definitely not await inside of a promise handler.

Comment: Thank you Doug! Much appreciated. I removed the cronjob and changed code: `return request(optionsAPI).then(mollieResponse => {
            return updateOrCreatePaymentInDb(userId, orderId, mollieResponse).then(() => {
                return updatePaymentIdInOrder(orderId, mollieResponse.id)
            });`